# AWS JS SDK V3 (Lambda module) - Unable to connect to instance metadata service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I was previously using the all-in-one `aws-sdk` npm module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) to invoke an AWS Lambda function, and for that the following code had been working well:

```
        //Some code to get "credentials"
        ...
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
            region: Config.REGION
        });
        lambda.invoke(pullParams, (err, data) =>
            //I would do something with data
        );
        ...
```

Now, taking a cue from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3,  I wish to use to modularised `@aws-sdk/client-lambda-node`, since it is the only class that I need in my project. Thus, I have changed my code (as suggested here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/master/packages/client-lambda-node#usage) like so:

```
        import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda-node/Lambda";
        /*
          I believe there is a typo in the form of 
          "
           import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/@aws-sdk/client-lambda-node/Lambda";
          "
          at the original page
        */
        ...
        //Some code to get the same "credentials" as above
        const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
            region: Config.REGION
        });
        lambda.invokeAsync(pullParams, (err, data) =>
            //I want to do something with err / data
        );
        ...
```

For what its worth, this is inside a ReactJS app (though I'm sure thats not relevant). Trying the above code with version `0.1.0-preview.5` inside a browser (where it worked earlier) perpetually gives me

1. `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
2. `Error: Unable to connect to instance metadata service` (I guess related to (1))

Is the library unstable for use, or am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass your credentials using key `credentials`.
Like:

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
    },
    region: Config.REGION
});
```

Or:

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    credentials,
    region: Config.REGION
});
```

Comment: I am using the NodeJS V3 SDK and that did the tick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, version 3 of the SDK is still in beta preview and [they've stated](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/new-aws-sdk-for-javascript-developer-preview/) that breaking changes are to be expected:

> While the SDK is in preview, you may encounter bugs.

To answer your question, yes, it is *absolutely unstable* for production at the present time. Your specific issue is quite common and I was unable to get to the bottom of it either. My production work all uses v2 still.

Comment: whats the install command that you use at work?

Comment: wrong parameters were passed to the client config